# Set 24-bit colors terminal (Truecolor) for Solarized theme on Mac

Tags: osx, colors, term

I am trying to get Solarized theme color correct in terminal by enabling truecolor on my Mac, following the instruction from Spacemaces:  https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/wiki/Terminal.

But I got error when I set `TERM=xterm-24bit`:

```
$ TERM=xterm-24bit
zsh: can't find terminal definition for xterm-24bit
```

I also tried to put compiled terminfo into `/usr/share/terminfo`, not working.

I also tried to set `TERMINFO` to `$HOME/.terminfo`, not working.

I am using iTerm2 3.2.1, Emacs 26.1, macOS 10.14 and Spacemacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out to be a problem with the `tic` I use.

Because I installed latest `miniconda` and included it in `PATH`, so when I run `which tic` I got `/Users/Yuji/miniconda/bin/tic`. Once I changed to use system `tic`, problem solved. Here is the code:

```
/usr/bin/tic  -x -o ~/.terminfo  xterm-24bit.terminfo
```

Hope this helps!