# emacs: cannot open terminfo database file

Tags: fonts, terminal-emacs, terminfo

I've created a new terminfo entry to enable italics in my terminal, as described [here](https://medium.com/@dubistkomisch/how-to-actually-get-italics-and-true-colour-to-work-in-iterm-tmux-vim-9ebe55ebc2be). The new terminfo entry looks like:

```
xterm-256color-italic|xterm with 256 colors and italic,
  sitm=\E[em, ritm=\E[23m,
  use=xterm-256color,
```

and it's saved to `~/xterm-256color-italic.terminfo`.

I installed the new terminfo entry by running `tic -x xterm-256color-italic.terminfo`. I see the compiled terminfo file in `~/.terminfo/78/xterm-256color-italic`. When I `export TERM=xterm-256color-italic` and run `infocmp`, I see:

```
#   Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /Users/rpatnaik/.terminfo/78/xterm-256color-italic
xterm-256color-italic|xterm with 256 colors and italic,
    am, bce, ccc, km, mc5i, mir, msgr, npc, xenl,
    colors#0x100, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#0x10000,
    acsc=``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
    bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, cbt=\E[Z, civis=\E[?25l,
    clear=\E[H\E[2J, cnorm=\E[?12l\E[?25h, cr=\r,
    csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=^H,
    cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=\n, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
    cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
    cvvis=\E[?12;25h, dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dim=\E[2m,
    dl=\E[%p1%dM, dl1=\E[M, ech=\E[%p1%dX, ed=\E[J, el=\E[K,
    el1=\E[1K, flash=\E[?5h$<100/>\E[?5l, home=\E[H,
    hpa=\E[%i%p1%dG, ht=^I, hts=\EH, ich=\E[%p1%d@,
    il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[L, ind=\n, indn=\E[%p1%dS,
    initc=\E]4;%p1%d;rgb\:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\E\\,
    invis=\E[8m, is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, kDC=\E[3;2~,
    kEND=\E[1;2F, kHOM=\E[1;2H, kIC=\E[2;2~, kLFT=\E[1;2D,
    kNXT=\E[6;2~, kPRV=\E[5;2~, kRIT=\E[1;2C, kb2=\EOE, kbs=^H,
    kcbt=\E[Z, kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA,
    kdch1=\E[3~, kend=\EOF, kent=\EOM, kf1=\EOP, kf10=\E[21~,
    kf11=\E[23~, kf12=\E[24~, kf13=\E[1;2P, kf14=\E[1;2Q,
    kf15=\E[1;2R, kf16=\E[1;2S, kf17=\E[15;2~, kf18=\E[17;2~,
    kf19=\E[18;2~, kf2=\EOQ, kf20=\E[19;2~, kf21=\E[20;2~,
    kf22=\E[21;2~, kf23=\E[23;2~, kf24=\E[24;2~,
    kf25=\E[1;5P, kf26=\E[1;5Q, kf27=\E[1;5R, kf28=\E[1;5S,
    kf29=\E[15;5~, kf3=\EOR, kf30=\E[17;5~, kf31=\E[18;5~,
    kf32=\E[19;5~, kf33=\E[20;5~, kf34=\E[21;5~,
    kf35=\E[23;5~, kf36=\E[24;5~, kf37=\E[1;6P, kf38=\E[1;6Q,
    kf39=\E[1;6R, kf4=\EOS, kf40=\E[1;6S, kf41=\E[15;6~,
    kf42=\E[17;6~, kf43=\E[18;6~, kf44=\E[19;6~,
    kf45=\E[20;6~, kf46=\E[21;6~, kf47=\E[23;6~,
    kf48=\E[24;6~, kf49=\E[1;3P, kf5=\E[15~, kf50=\E[1;3Q,
    kf51=\E[1;3R, kf52=\E[1;3S, kf53=\E[15;3~, kf54=\E[17;3~,
    kf55=\E[18;3~, kf56=\E[19;3~, kf57=\E[20;3~,
    kf58=\E[21;3~, kf59=\E[23;3~, kf6=\E[17~, kf60=\E[24;3~,
    kf61=\E[1;4P, kf62=\E[1;4Q, kf63=\E[1;4R, kf7=\E[18~,
    kf8=\E[19~, kf9=\E[20~, khome=\EOH, kich1=\E[2~,
    kind=\E[1;2B, kmous=\E[<, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~,
    kri=\E[1;2A, mc0=\E[i, mc4=\E[4i, mc5=\E[5i, meml=\El,
    memu=\Em, oc=\E]104\007, op=\E[39;49m, rc=\E8,
    rep=%p1%c\E[%p2%{1}%-%db, rev=\E[7m, ri=\EM,
    rin=\E[%p1%dT, ritm=\E[23m, rmacs=\E(B, rmam=\E[?7l,
    rmcup=\E[?1049l\E[23;0;0t, rmir=\E[4l, rmkx=\E[?1l\E>,
    rmm=\E[?1034l, rmso=\E[27m, rmul=\E[24m,
    rs1=\Ec\E]104\007, rs2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, sc=\E7,
    setab=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;%p1%d%;m,
    setaf=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m,
    sgr=%?%p9%t\E(0%e\E(B%;\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p5%t;2%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p7%t;8%;m,
    sgr0=\E(B\E[m, sitm=\E[3m, smacs=\E(0, smam=\E[?7h,
    smcup=\E[?1049h\E[22;0;0t, smir=\E[4h, smkx=\E[?1h\E=,
    smm=\E[?1034h, smso=\E[7m, smul=\E[4m, tbc=\E[3g,
    u6=\E[%i%d;%dR, u7=\E[6n, u8=\E[?%[;0123456789]c,
    u9=\E[c, vpa=\E[%i%p1%dd,
```

which indicates to me that the terminfo entry has been installed correctly. However, when I run `emacs -nw`, I get: `emacs: cannot open terminfo database file`. I've verified that `~/.terminfo` and the termcap file are both world-readable, so it shouldn't be a permission issue. I'm wondering where I go from here -- it looks like I've configured everything correctly, and the error message gives me no further details.

I'm running emacs 26.2, which I've installed from Homebrew. This is running on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Answer (score 3):

So, I have found 2 solutions for 2 different terminal emulators.

1. with Kitty terminal emulator
2. with Alacritty terminal emulator

---

## Kitty

Using the Kitty terminal emulator I had the same issue, I was following the emacs [FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Colors-on-a-TTY.html)

The fix was to do `use=xterm-kitty` instead of `use=xterm-256color`.

So I used:

```
 xterm-emacs|xterm with 24-bit direct color mode for Emacs,
   use=xterm-kitty,
   setb24=\E[48\:2\:\:%p1%{65536}%/%d\:%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&\
      %d\:%p1%{255}%&%dm,
   setf24=\E[38\:2\:\:%p1%{65536}%/%d\:%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&\
      %d\:%p1%{255}%&%dm,
```

then

```
$ tic -x -o ~/.terminfo terminfo-custom.src
```

and you can do

```
$ TERM=xterm-emacs emacs -nw
```

why does it work? I have no idea, but it didn't work following the `xterm-256color`, I would get

```
emacs: cannot open terminfo database file
```

[Related GitHub issue on the Kitty repo](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues/1141)

---

## Alacritty

From this other [SO question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45093/set-24-bit-colors-terminal-truecolor-for-solarized-theme-on-mac), the following worked by following the FAQ, but using this `tic`:

```
/usr/bin/tic -x -o ~/.terminfo terminfo-custom.src
```

and, works!

when I do `which tic` I get `/opt/local/bin/tic` and I guess that one gave me issue.

Comment: I don't have this issue any more. Something between updating to Catalina, updating emacs, and updating iTerm2 fixed the problem.